# Decimal conversion not happening for tr-TR culture

Tags: c#-3.0

I have very simple code

```
Decimal Value=34.23m;
Decimal spent;
spent = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(Value)), 2);
Spent = 34.23
```

It works fine for en-GB culture

If my culture is defined as 'tr-TR' then it fails to convert as the above 
it displays as 3423.

Not sure why this is causing such a difference.

Code:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            string culture = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CultureDefaultloc"];
            //  string culture = "zh-CN";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
            {
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
}

<add key="CultureDefaultloc" value="tr-TR"/>
```

Comment: Can you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to use Convert.ToDecimal() on a value that is already of type Decimal.  Surely it is actually a string?  This goes wrong because the decimal point in some cultures is not a period but a comma.  Use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture instead, pass it to the Decimal.Parse() overload.